# Do SMART technologies and HDD Surface Scans do the same thing?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, smart, disk-utility

There are utilities that check/revive/update the bad block list by systematically reading each block of data on a hard disk and write it while other utilities rely on SMART monitoring.

Are they the same -- two approaches to the same end solution?

Thanks

Comment: No they are not the same. One uses the SMART data log, the other actually reads each block of data in real time.

Answer (score 2):

No they are not the same because the outcome is different.

When reading every sector of a hard disk you can build a list of unreadable sectors. You know their location and the total number.

When checking SMART data you will only get the total number of unreadable sectors.

When running a tool that is operating a level above not dealing with sectors but with clusters instead (chkdsk on NTFS p.e.) you get a result on cluster level which is maybe 8 times less precise.
If for instance one cluster consists of 8 sectors of 512 byte and one sector fails to read the cluster will be marked as bad, making the content of 7 sectors unavailable for the file system. Nevertheless there are 7 readable sectors left over which might be useful for recovery purposes.
A NTFS-type bad cluster list will not disclose that detailed information.

Added 15.5.2020 for your comment:
"SMART technologies" provides much more information about a hard drive than "HDD surfaces Scans". When limiting the need of information to readibility of sectors a "HDD surface scan" that includes the whole drive provides you with updated detailed information on block level but not an sector level.

Despite this disadvantage of lack of precision this information is more detailed than the SMART parameters which only show you the number of unreadable sectors.

Comment: So if I have a hard disk and I want to "truly" know how it is a surface scan is more accurate.